# Get next or previous element in array by clicking prev or next button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following problem:

I have two divs, only one of these is shown and when I click the next or the previous button the other one is shown and the one which was visible is set to hidden. The div which is shown has the "active" class. Now, I need to get the id of the div which has this class. The problem is that I always get the id of the previous one because when I click the button I get first the id and then the class is changed..and I don't know why, also if the code which change the class is written before the code which get the id.

How can I fix this?

```
<div class="item <?php if($i == 1) echo 'active';?>" id="<?php echo $dati['id'];?>">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-content">
                <h1><?php echo $dati['titolo'];?></h1>
                <p class="lead">
                  <?php echo $desc_feed;?>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


 <a class="prev" href="#main-slider" id="next-carousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></a>
    <a class="next" href="#main-slider" id="prev-carousel" data-slide="next"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
```

```
function show_feed_data(id)
{
    get_feed_data(id);
}




$( "#prev-carousel" ).click(function() {
    var id_feed_to_show = $(".active").attr("id");
    get_feed_data(id_feed_to_show);
});

$( "#next-carousel" ).click(function() {
    var id_feed_to_show = $(".active").attr("id");
    get_feed_data(id_feed_to_show);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are getting the ID of the current `active` element before it fires the carousel to change the class.

Let's each of the carousel divs are siblings (next to each other) . You can do it like this :

```
$( "#prev-carousel" ).click(function() {
    var id_feed_to_show = $(".active").prev().attr('id');
    get_feed_data(id_feed_to_show);
});

$( "#next-carousel" ).click(function() {
    var id_feed_to_show = $(".active").next().attr("id");
    get_feed_data(id_feed_to_show);
});
```

Comment: now i get only the first id..the second one is undefined